# Explanation of hyperbola drawing

Tags: conic-sections

Here is an image of a hyperbola:

[image]

I'm wondering why $c^2=a^2+b^2$ in this drawing given that $c$ is the distance from the origin to both of the foci and $a$ is half the length of the absolute distance between any given point and the two foci.

Sorry if this seems like a stupid question.

Comment: I know, but why is the distance from the middle to the foci the hypotenuse?

Comment: Edit: My bad - I see now, haha

Comment: I believe http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hyperbola.html shows this. It starts with the foci being $2c$ apart and the intercepts being $2a$ apart and shows that the cartesian equation is $\frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}}-\frac {y^{2}}{c^2-a^{2}}=1$. Next, notice the asymptotes have slope $\pm \frac{b}{a}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the foci of the hyperbola $F_1=(c,0)$ and $F_2=(-c,0)$ and the two vertices : $V_1=(a,0)$ and $V_2=(-a,0)$.

From the definition we have that a point $P$ of the hyperbola is such that $\overline{PF_1}-\overline{PF_2}=k$, and using as $P$ a vertex we find that $k=2a$.

So, for $P=(x,y)$ the equation is 
$$
\sqrt{(x-c)^2+y^2}-\sqrt{(x+c)^2+y^2}=2a
$$

squarin two times and with ambit of algebra you can find the equation:

$$
\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{c^2-a^2}=1
$$

that becomes 
$$
\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1
$$
with $b^2=c^2-a^2$

and this means that $c^2=a^2+b^2$. Then note that the asymptotes of the hyperbola have slope $\pm\frac{b}{a}$, so the asymptotes intrecept the circle with center the origin and radius $c$ at the points of coordinates $(\pm a,\pm b)$ where $a^2+b^2=c^2$

Comment: So, one just makes a arbitrary substitution?

Comment: why ''arbitrary''? We know that $c^2-a^2>0$ so it can be write as a square of a real number that is the hypotenuse of a rectangular triangle with the other sides $a$ and $c$.

Comment: So it is arbitrary. Okay, thanks so much.